# Color box issue

Tags: formatting, color

Here is my MWE (minimal working example):

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
     {\setlength{\fboxsep}{2.5pt}\colorbox{Orange}{ 9}}

     {\setlength{\fboxsep}{2.5pt}\colorbox{Orange}{ 10}}
     \end{center}
\end{document}
```

### Question

How can I make the orange box around 10 as wide as the one around 9 so they line up?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of making the box containing 10 narrow, I would make box containing 9 broader.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{calc}   %% provides \widthof macro


\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
     {\setlength{\fboxsep}{2.5pt}\colorbox{Orange}{\makebox[\widthof{10}][c]{9}}}

     {\setlength{\fboxsep}{2.5pt}\colorbox{Orange}{10}}
     \end{center}

     \begin{center}
     {\setlength{\fboxsep}{2.5pt}\colorbox{Orange}{9}}

     {\setlength{\fboxsep}{2.5pt}\colorbox{Orange}{\makebox[\widthof{9}][c]{10}}}
     \end{center}    

\end{document}
```

[image]